# jQuery drop down menu .slideUp() not working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two divs with a jQuery drop down menu. When I click anywhere on a document an active menu slides up, but when I click on another div with the jQuery drop-down menu, the previously opened menu remains open.

**HTML (example)**

```
<div id="menu-act" class="menu-button">
<ul class="no-js">
    <li>
    <a id="btnclick" class="actions">Actions</a>
    <ul class="action-options">
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="menu-act2" class="menu-button">
<ul class="no-js">
    <li>
    <a id="btnclick2" class="actions">Actions</a>
    <ul class="action-options">
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery (example)**

```
$(function() {
        $("#menu-act > ul").toggleClass("no-js js");
        $("#menu-act .js ul").hide();
        $("#menu-act .js").click(function(e) {
            $("#menu-act .js ul").slideToggle(100);
            $("#btnclick").toggleClass("active");
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    $("#menu-act2 > ul").toggleClass("no-js js");
        $("#menu-act2 .js ul").hide();
        $("#menu-act2 .js").click(function(e) {
            $("#menu-act2 .js ul").slideToggle(100);
            $("#btnclick2").toggleClass("active");
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).click(function() {
        if ($('.menu-button .js ul').is(':visible')) {
            $('.menu-button .js ul', this).slideUp(10);
            $('.actions').removeClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/56ycx/1/

How do I make any previously open menu hide when I click another drop-down menu?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML, and create a demo in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/56ycx/4/)**

I think its simple as it is

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $(".menu-button .action-options").hide();
    $(".menu-button ul a").click(function (e) {
      $(".menu-button .action-options").hide();
     $(this).parents('ul').find('.action-options').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {

        $(".menu-button .action-options").hide();
        return true;
    });
});
```

### Edited code according to OP requirement

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/5JMYY/)

Try this new code,according to the requirement mentioned.

```
$('.menu-button .action-options').hide();
$('.menu-button .actions').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parents('ul').find('.action-options').is(':visible')) {

        $(this).parents('ul').find('.action-options').slideUp(10);
        $('.actions').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.menu-button .action-options').slideUp(10);
        $(this).parents('ul').find('.action-options').slideDown(10);
        $('.actions').addClass('active');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function (e) {

    $(".menu-button .action-options").hide();
    return true;
});
```

Hope this helps ,Thank you

Comment: This is a whole new code. I can't modify my code. Is there a way just to say that if another button is clicked then just hide all other opened menus but not the one you just clicked? Like, for example here condtion executes on document click `$(document).click(function() {if ($('.menu-button .js ul').is(':visible'))....`. I tried to play with a code but cant make it work properly.

Comment: Here what I tried `$('.menu-button .js .actions').click(function() {if ($(this, 'ul.action-options').siblings().is(':visible')) {$('.menu-button .js ul.action-options', this).slideUp(10);$('.actions').removeClass('active');}});`

Comment: @dimit you code is not clean. it decreases the performance. you are using a lot of objects when it can be done with simple. Using jquery objects a lot will decrease the performance

Comment: @dmit Changed the code according to your need Check the edit in the above answer.Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the extra help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
$('.DropDownMenu li').click(function() {
    var $that = $(this);

    // Slides Up, all menu items, and removes class active on Complete.
    $('.DropDown .MenuItem li').slideUp(10, function(){
         $that.removeClass('active');
    });

    // Slides Down, clicked menu item, and adds class "active" on Complete.
    $that.slideDown(10, function(){
         $that.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not really work for me, could you please see my two comments in the next answer, may be some suggestions will occur in light of that info?